# \input gives error, but copy-pasting the code does not

Tags: input, external-files, examdesign

I have the following `main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{examdesign}

\begin{document}    

\begin{examtop}
{\LARGE Math Test}
\end{examtop}

\begin{multiplechoice}[rearrange=no]
\input{myquestion.tex}
\end{multiplechoice}

\end{document}
```

And the myquestion.tex file as follows:

```
\begin{question}
What is 2+2?

\choice{1}
\choice{2}
\choice[!]{4}
\choice{-3}
\choice{7}
\end{question}
```

This gives me an error with the input statement in main.tex.  The error says that

> File ended while scanning use of \get@instructions

but I don't know what it means. However, when I replace the input line with the question, the error disappears. How can I input the code without copy-pasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write following macros in your preamble:

```
\newread\questionfile
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\inputquestion #1{\par
   \def\tmpa{\begin{multiplechoice}[rearrange=no]}
   \openin\questionfile=#1
   \loop
      \unless\ifeof\questionfile 
         \read\questionfile to\tmpb
         \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tmpa\expandafter{\tmpb}
   \repeat
   \closein\questionfile
   \tmpa \end{multiplechoice}
}
```

Then you can use this macro:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{examtop}
{\LARGE Math Test}
\end{examtop}

\inputquestion{myquestion.tex}

\end{document}
```

Your problem is that internals ot the the LaTeX macro `\begin{multiplechoice}` run to scan following text as macro definition until `\end{multiplechoice}` occurs. But such `\end{multiplechoice}` isn't at the same file level as the scanned text. The scanning ends with TeX error because classical TeX doesn't allow to continue of scanning in another file than it starts.

Comment: Thank you very much for the smart solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem. -> add begin{multiplechoice} enviroment to the myquestion.tex.

This is the myquestion.tex file

```
\begin{multiplechoice}[rearrange=no]    
\begin{question}
    What is 2+2?    
    \choice{1}
    \choice{2}
    \choice[!]{4}
    \choice{-3}
    \choice{7}
\end{question}
\end{multiplechoice}
```

Main file:

```
\documentclass{examdesign}

\begin{document}    

\begin{examtop}
{\LARGE Math Test}
\end{examtop}

\input{myquestion.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to solve the problem without modifying the questions?